# PHP - generating an HTML element for each unique set of values in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a `<ul>` generated from a MySQL DB table with this PHP script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM city_list ORDER BY city_state");

echo "<ul class=\"chapter-list\">";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<li data-state=\"" . $row['city_state'] . "\">" . $row['city_name'] . "</li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

The output looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li data-state="alabama">Birmingham</li>
  <li data-state="alabama">Bear Creek</li>
  <li data-state="alabama">Belk</li>
  <li data-state="kansas">Topeka</li>
  <li data-state="kansas">Olathe</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to generate a header as an `<li>` element before each group of a particular `data-state` value. So, I'd like to end up with markup like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Alabama</li>
  <li data-state="alabama">Birmingham</li>
  <li data-state="alabama">Bear Creek</li>
  <li data-state="alabama">Belk</li>
  <li>Kansas</li>
  <li data-state="kansas">Topeka</li>
  <li data-state="kansas">Olathe</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a PHP array function to do something like this, or will I probably have to resort to something with JS? I've been through the PHP docs, but haven't found a solution yet. I'm a beginner in PHP, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Change your query to `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM city_list ORDER BY city_state`, probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach. Each time there is a new `$row['city_state']`, the if condition will be true, and it will echo out a new header:

```
$last_state = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($last_state != $row['city_state']){
        echo '<li>' . ucfirst($row['city_state']) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '<li data-state="' . $row['city_state'] . '">' . $row['city_name'] . '</li>';
    $last_state = $row['city_state'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks [LarsAnders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3258572/larsanders) - works great! Is the `!=` what's doing the trick in your code?

Comment: Yes, that and the exact spot where we assign a value to `$last_state`. It's basically checking for a difference between the value at the end of the last loop, and the value from the newly loaded row. The very first time through, `$last_state` isn't equal to the new row either, so the first header gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previous value of `$row["city_state"]` to a variable outside the while loop and check if the new `$row["city_state"]` equals the old. If the two values are not equal you add an item like this `'<li data-state="'.$row["city_state"].'">'."Something".'</li>'`

**EDIT:**
larsAnders' code is exactly what I meant :)